# Sending packets to 127.0.0.1 through gopcap

Tags: linux, go, network-programming, pcap

It seems that packets sent through using gopacket/gopcap are somehow 'sent' as they are visible in a tshark trace:

```
444 143.613451037    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    UDP 66 6000 → 8888 Len=22
```

but these packets never arrive on a process on the same machine listening on 127.0.0.1:8888 (for example `netcat -ul 8888`).

Does anybody have any hints on why this is or things to try? As mentioned, the packets are in fact visible in a tshark trace... they just seem to completely vanish after that.

```
... irrelevant
out , err := pcap.OpenLive(*iface, 65535, true, -1 * time.Second)
out.WritePacketData(buf.Bytes())
... irrevelant
```

The idea is to construct packets and send them on `lo` so that a process listening on `127.0.0.1:<some port>` can actually see those packets.

IP src/dst are both 127.0.0.1 and ethernet src/dst are both 00:00:00:00:00:00.

**Edit:**

As far as some more research goes it seems to be the case that sending packets with pcap bypasses IP network stacks in such a way that the packets can't be seen by processes. A workaround is to strip the lower levels of the packets in the trace and open a regular udp/tcp socket and send the payload through that socket.

Comment: Wild guess. Are some local firewall rules dropping the packet due to some rules protecting against spoofing? Does this happen also if your firewall rules are cleared/off ?

Comment: nah... it seems that pcap bypasses the ip stack.

Comment: What are the Ethernet addresses on packets in the pcap? How did you capture the pcap? Did you change its content before sending it?

Comment: I captured them on the local machine so the addresses should be fine.

Comment: for what it's worth: the ethernet addresses are all zeroes (probably because its `lo` and not an `eth*`). ip src and dst are 127.0.0.1 obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As far as some more research goes it seems to be the case that sending packets with pcap bypasses IP network stacks in such a way that the packets can't be seen by processes. A workaround is to strip the lower levels of the packets in the trace and open a regular udp/tcp socket and send the payload through that socket.